"Apache error with misformatted or invalid characters in route containing ':' on local WAMP server"
I'm running a Slim Framework project locally on a WAMP server using Apache. In certain routes that contain the : character (e.g. /solicitudes:nuevo), I get the following error in the Apache log:

(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: AH00127: Cannot map GET /solicitudes:nuevo

I tried various solutions, including updating the .htaccess file with AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode and rewriting the route using RewriteRule, but nothing seems to work. This error only occurs on my local environment (WAMP with Apache 2.4), while it works fine on other environments.
How can I handle this route without changing the actual application URLs?
I attempted the following solutions to address the issue with routes containing the : character:
Added AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode to .htaccess:
Expected: To allow Apache to handle routes with encoded slashes correctly.
Result: Encountered an Internal Server Error, as this directive is not allowed in .htaccess.
Moved AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode to httpd-vhost.conf:
Expected: To configure Apache to allow encoded slashes in URLs globally.
Result: The issue with misformatted paths still persists, and the error logs show that Apache cannot map the route.
Rewrote the route in .htaccess:
Rewrite Rule: RewriteRule ^solicitudes:nuevo$ solicitudes-nuevo [PT,L]
Expected: To rewrite the route with : to a format Apache can handle.
Result: The error persists, indicating that the route is still misformatted or contains invalid characters.
Despite these attempts, the issue remains unresolved and only occurs locally on my WAMP setup.

How did you get on with my answer?

WAMP - Windows. The "problem" is that the : (colon) character is not a valid character in Windows filenames. This is ultimately a limitation of the Windows OS. (You do not get the same error on Apache/Linux.)
When you make a request to the webserver (Apache), the requested URL ultimately gets mapped to the filesystem. It is at this point the error occurs (which normally triggers a "403 Forbidden" response). Unfortunately, .htaccess is processed after the request has already been mapped to the filesystem, so this cannot be resolved in .htaccess.
However, this can be resolved if you have access to the main server (or Virtual Host) config. (Otherwise, you would need to change these URLs if you are using Apache on a Windows server.)
AllowEncodedSlashes is not relevant here. This directive is only to do with allowing URL encoded (forward) slashes (%2F) and backslashes (%5C) in the URL-path/path-info part of the URL.

RewriteRule ^solicitudes:nuevo$ solicitudes-nuevo [PT,L]


As mentioned above, attempting to resolve this in .htaccess is not going to work (it's too late). However, simply rewriting the request to another arbitrary URL is unlikely to work anyway (the framework is not going to see the rewritten URL - although maybe that's the intention as a different URL would be mapped to the filesystem?).
You could try moving the existing slim front-controller pattern from .htaccess (a directory context) to the main server config (or <VirtualHost> container). Not a <Directory> container (that's effectively the same as .htaccess - but in the server) as that also runs too late. This allows the request to be internally rewritten to the front-controller (ie. index.php) before the request is mapped to the filesystem.
However, in moving the directives from .htaccess (a directory context) to either the main server block (server context) or <VirtualHost> container (virtualhost context) you need to modify the directives since the directives are processed much earlier (before the request is mapped to the filesystem)
If your .htaccess file currently looks like this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]

Source: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html

Then the corresponding directives when used in a server context would be something like:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.+) /index.php [L]

(The QSA flag was unnecessary in the original code block.)
In a server context, REQUEST_FILENAME still contains the requested URL (not the filename), so attempting to use this directly in a server context to perform filesystem checks will always fail. Instead, it's easier to manually construct the filename from the document-root and requested URL-path.

I'm just curious, why would you expect 403 Forbidden response? That response means that client is not authorized to access requested resource. Personally, I would expect either 400 Bad Request as the requested URL doesn't conform to urls accepted by server or 501 Not Implemented as the url is valid based on RFC but server implementation doesn't support it.

@MichalHynčica A 403 is "expected" simply because that is what Apache on Windows "normally" responds with in this scenario - whether that is strictly the "correct" HTTP status code is another matter.

@MichalHynčica I've changed the wording in my answer to remove "expect"; if that was causing some confusion. Thanks.

I see, thanks. I've never experienced this issue so I didn't know that's usual apache's response in that case. Maybe the part before : is interpreted as drive and apache believes the path is outside of document root (or other folders with allowed access).
